# NuGet pulls down different dependency versions for same code on different computers

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

My co-worker and I are both using Visual Studio 2013. We are both working from the same code base. When I pull down NuGet packages from a custom repository (local file share), I get newer versions of dependent assemblies than he gets. We have both cleared our NuGet caches and we still see the same behavior.

Additionally, when I pull the packages, my app.config gets updated with assemblyBinding entries while his does not. He is still able to debug the code in VS, but the different versions and app.config changes cause problems in my environment. This seems like an environmental issue, but I don't know what could be causing this.

I am totally stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Things to verify: you're using the same version of the NuGet package manager as shown under Tools > Extension and Updates, and also you have the same feeds.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. We were just going down that path... his environment is more updated than mine so I am running updates now.